# Does Android Studio provide a way to test interactions between devices?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, automated-tests

While developing an app I more and more stumble upon the fact that I need to run interaction tests where two emulators are running the app to ensure the entire integration is working by testing the interaction between those (and not mock one of the devices)

During research on the topic (which is quite hard to search for because I do not want to run the *same* tests on *multiple devices*) I found a couple of solutions, however none of them seem to integrate very well into an Android Studio workflow. Some tools I've found:

- [UiAutomator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing)
- [UI/Application Exerciser Monkey](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkey)
- [Appmium](http://appium.io/)
- Some blend of adb, ruby, python etc.
- Some projects on github

My expectation may be off but is there no framework or tool with a similar level of integration like running an instrumented tests that allows me to connect to several devices and perform interactions on them together?

Some of those approaches above require out-of-the-tool tinkering with adb or require a lot of environment to be set up.

Answer (score 0):

Good answer to this question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49647422/14338677

In short:
1.Create communication proxy that will be between sender and receiver
2.Add build type autoresponder, and communication proxy code get empty if (!BuildConfig.AUTORESPONDER)
3.Install autoresponder app to emulator or device when you will be testing
4.Run another test app with Espresso that can communicate with autoresponder app
5.Use Thread.sleep(...) to wait response of autoresponder app